# Devise: Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I don't know why, but the following code just stopped working (I didn't even notice how it happened)

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, components: {registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions'}
```

**registations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:name, :surname, :username, :email, :avatar)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:name, :surname, :email, :avatar)
  end

end
```

As I said, everything worked fine before, but now I'm getting:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lvuPOmTRqv6XUQ/O1g4Q9VNvzD7DgGCHocY/OlAvKHEIvWAHvlS982hxSZZzzAESCpmL5QTUcTLw/c9ME/sUFQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Doe", "username"=>"foobar", "email"=>"foobar@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Unpermitted parameters: name, surname, email
```

Cofiguration:

- Rails 4.2.5
- Devise 3.5.6

*P.S.: Now I finally understand why should I cover my code with unit-tests and use Travis CI*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should try  "configure_permitted_parameters" method  in application controller instead of registration controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:name, :surname,:username, :email, :avatar)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:name, :surname, :email, :avatar)
 end
end
```

Comment: I helped me. But why? What happened with the previous code?

Comment: The `for` method has been deprecated since 4.1. Use this instead:

Comment: Here the same link provided by @KinjalShah but pointing directly to the section about strong parameters: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#user-content-strong-parameters

Answer (score 27):

The `for` method has been deprecated since 4.1. Use this instead:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:name, :surname,:username, :email, :avatar]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

along the 4.5.0 documentation:

> In case you want to permit additional parameters (the lazy way™), you
>   can do so using a simple before filter in your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

works for me (with Rails 5.2.1).

With nested parameters (untested):

> nested attributes (say you're using accepts_nested_attributes_for),
>   then you will need to tell devise about those nestings and types:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, 
           address_attributes: [:country, :state, :city, :area, :postal_code]])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue while using the [Devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise) gem. It was caused because I added an `email_confirmation` parameter to the `users` model in my Rails application without whitelisting the parameter in the `users_controller`.

**Here's how I solved it:**

1. Simply open the `users_controller`
2. Add the `email_confirmation` parameter to the list of permitted parameters in the `users_params` action.
3. Save and then reload your browser.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**